# Two Bind placeholders in one NavigateUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to put a variable for the product number by using Routing like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" NavigateUrl='<%$ RouteUrl:v=p, productId=1%>' runat="server">
```

Instead of (1) i want to put <%# Bind("productId")> i'm wondering how to migrate them together

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl("p", new {productId = Eval("id")}) %>'
```